# reload containerized fluentd configuration

Tags: docker, fluentd

Supposing my container is named fluentd, I'd expect this command to reload the config:

```
sudo docker kill -s HUP fluentd
```

Instead it kills the container.

Seems there is some spawning of a few processes from the entrypoint:

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
1 root       0:00 {entrypoint.sh} /usr/bin/dumb-init /bin/sh /bin/entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/pl
5 root       0:00 /bin/sh /bin/entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/plugins $FLUENTD_OPT
13 fluent     0:00 /bin/sh -c fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/plugins $FLUENTD_OPT
14 fluent     0:00 {fluentd} /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf -p /fluentd/plugins
16 fluent     0:00 {fluentd} /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf -p /fluentd/plugins
```

Tried HUPping from inside the container pid 13 and it seems to work.

Docker is sending the signal to the entrypoint. If I inspect the State.Pid, I see 4450. Here's the host ps:

```
root      4450  4432  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dumb-init /bin/sh /bin/entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c fluentd -c 
/fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/plugins $FLUENTD_OPT
root      4467  4450  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /bin/entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/plugins $FLUENTD_OPT
ubuntu    4475  4467  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/${FLUENTD_CONF} -p /fluentd/plugins $FLUENTD_OPT
ubuntu    4476  4475  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf -p /fluentd/plugins
ubuntu    4478  4476  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf -p /fluentd/plugins
```

Any ideas how do reload the conf without a custom script to find the correct process to HUP?

Comment: Did you find anyway to send SIGHUP to fluentd within the container? I tried all lf them but one of them really made it to reload.

Answer (score 4):

This command should work I believe

```
sudo docker exec fluentd pkill -1 -x fluentd
```

I tested it on sleep command inside fluentd container and it works.

Comment: Sending  '-1 -x sh' works. The fluentd processes are apparently the lowest children so you have to get their parent.

Comment: On second look, the sh selects two processes, the entrypoint and the child, and sending the hup to both doesn't work. Can do some fancy work trying to select the child with grep and awk and such, but not worth it. I'll just restart the container.

Comment: `docker kill --signal=HUP fluentd_container_id`

Comment: Since version 1.9.0, it has been changed to SIGUSR2(12). 
(https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/signals#sigusr2)

ex) docker exec fluentd pkill -12 -x fluentd

Answer (score 0):

In my case fluentd is running as a pod on kubernetes.
The command that works for me is:

```bash
kubectl -n=elastic-system exec -it fluentd-pch5b -- kill  --signal SIGHUP 7
```

Where the number `7` is the process id of fluentd inside the container
as you can see below:

```bash
root@fluentd-pch5b:/home/fluent# ps -elf
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root         1     0  0  80   0 -  2075 -      14:42 ?        00:00:00 tini -- /fluentd/entrypoint.sh
4 S root         7     1  0  80   0 - 56225 -      14:42 ?        00:00:02 ruby /fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.co
4 S root        19     7  0  80   0 - 102930 -     14:42 ?        00:00:06 /usr/local/bin/ruby -Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit /fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.
4 S root        70     0  0  80   0 -  2439 -      14:52 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
0 R root        82    70  0  80   0 -  3314 -      14:54 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -elf
```